# Android 3d model with lipsync

Tags: android, android-studio, model, 3d

I'm currently trying to have a 3D model in android, in sync with lipsync.
I have another apk which handles the speech (Gives at any current time what word is being spoken). The app I want to build is not a game, just a **3D model talking**.

Any ideas what engine should I use ?
What I found so far:

- **Rajawali for Native Android** : does not support quads, and I need high detailed 3D models. Also not sure how I would achieve lipsync here.
- **Unreal engine** : Can't find any documentation for receiving broadcasts from another apk

So before I settle with Unity (which has a lot documentation for android), do I have any other better options? Because I don't want to use game engines for such a "simple" task.